# No module named bson even though uninstall and install again

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker

I tried to import bson from a notebook on SageMaker with conda_python3 kernel but I have the error `No module named bson`

I tried the following in the notebook:

```
!python -m pip uninstall bson --yes
!python -m pip uninstall pymongo --yes
!pip install pymongo
```

But I still have the above error message. Any idea why? thanks!

Comment: You're using Anaconda, right?  I thought `conda` was for installing packages for Anaconda, not `pip`.

Comment: Did you try: `!pip install bson`?